# F.write doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os,sys
import time
from colorama import Fore,Back,Style,init
init(autoreset=True)
appdata_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"), os.pardir)
subpath = "Local/sieosp/filesav2292.sav"
f = open(os.path.join(appdata_path, subpath), "r+")
lines=f.readlines()
a1=int (lines[116])
a2=int (lines[120])
a3=int (lines[124])
b4=int (lines[128])
c5=int (lines[132])
d6=int (lines[136])
e7=int (lines[140])
d8=int (lines[144])
d9=int (lines[148])
d10=int (lines[152])
d11=int (lines[156])
d12=int (lines[160])
total=int (a1+a2+a3+b4+c5+d6+e7+d8+d9+d10+d11+d12)
if (total)==(12):
    print("You already own every character")
else:
   with f:
    userinputvalue=int (input("Type 1 if you want to unlock every character,or 0 if you would like to close this \n"))
    if(userinputvalue)==1:    
       lines[156]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[116]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[120]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[124]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[128]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[132]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[136]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[140]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[144]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[148]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[152]=f.write("1\n")
       lines[160]=f.write("1\n")
    else:
     print("Closing")
    time.sleep(1)
```

So this should work,right? Don't know why f.write doesn't write 1 to my file. am i using it very wrong? Searched around google for some more info but I didnt understand a thing :/ tried to use f.write as f.readlines but no luck. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you dont open the file in write mode, only in read mode.

f = open(os.path.join(appdata_path, subpath), "r+")

Change the "r" to a "w"

Comment: 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing ... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: I need both read and write,as I need to check wether or not the characters are unlocked,sorry if I was vague about that!

Answer (score 0):

You have opened the file with "r+", so the file is even writable, the problem is that if you open a file with "r+" you have to manage the pointer in the file, otherwise the string will be append at the end.

In order to manage it you have to use the function `f.seek(offset, from_what)` like described here [Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

For example in this code I change only the first line of the file:

```
f = open("File/Path/file.txt", "r+")
f.seek(0,0)
f.write("something")
f.close()
```

You also use `line[N] = f.write("something")`, careful to use it in this way, because it returns the number of characters wrote, not the characters wrote ;)